# Beginner with claw hand

Tags: acoustic-guitar, violin, keyboard, digital-piano, ukulele

What would be the best instrument  for me to play with my right hand having claw hand/MS? I have no experience but I’m interested in the guitar

Comment: Go for guitar. It seems like you'll do well with it. Good luck!

Comment: You’ll make it!  Mind Django Reinhardt: , https://www.quora.com/Would-I-have-an-issue-learning-to-play-acoustic-guitar-with-my-deformed-hand, look up the books from Moshe Feldenkrais: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosh%C3%A9_Feldenkrais and watch the videos with Nick Vujicic.

Comment: You could try guitar with a pick.  I am not sure what claw hand is and how severe it is.  Quite frankly you could also try percussion.  You'll get a full body workout.

Comment: French Horn is another candidate.  The right hand pretty much gets shoved up the bell, while the left hand does all the fingering.

Answer (score 2):

Play guitar, this is the perfect instrument for you, if not trombone.

If you are capable to handle the chords with your left you can strumm with your right hand the strings in any position of your fingers, and how ever you can pick them with one ore more fingers ... this would be the right compensation and therapy for you.

Feldenkrais was the teacher of David Ben Gurion and Yehudi Menhuin. He tells in his book *the elusive obvious* how he has watched to men with crutches and only one leg playing football!

P.S.

1. When I studied youth-psychology I gave guitarlessons to handy caped children. The conservatory teacher had counseled the parents that the kids weren’t talented. But I was convinced that this was the right compensatory program.
2. I’ve read from Feldenkrais when my sons wife was studying physiology:

*Moshe Feldenkrais, D.Sc., a visionary scientist who pioneered the field of mind-body education and therapy, has inspired countless people worldwide. His ability to translate his theories on human function into action resulted in the creation of his technique, now known as the Feldenkrais Method of Somatic Education. In The Potent Self, Feldenkrais delves deeply into the relationship between faulty posture, pain, and the underlying emotional mechanisms that lead to compulsive and dependent human behavior. He shares remarkable insights into resistance, motivation, habit formation, and the place of sex in full human potential. The Potent Self offers Feldenkrais' vision of how to achieve physical and mental wellness through the development of authentic maturity.*

[image]

**Books:**

- *Awareness through movement*
- *The potent self*
- *The elusive obvious*

https://epdf.pub/the-elusive-obvious-or-basic-feldenkrais.html

Comment: I love your English! 'Handy caped chldren'. So, Superman and his family lived nearby? Just joking, but I love it!  Try 'handicapped'. It's almost worth an upvote for that alone!

Comment: That's the way I like it!

Answer (score 0):

Consensus is that you can play a standard trumpet left-handed (saving the hassle of tracking down a semi-custom "mirrored" trumpet).

Off-the-wall:  if you can hold, or strap on, a mallet, consider hammer dulcimer, xylophone, vibraphone, and similar percussion instruments.